# CodeIgniter 3 with Whoops

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, whoops

I can't get this working to any error occurred in CI entirely, Whoops registered as early as possible by adding handlers to `index.php`.

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT)
{
    case 'development':
        error_reporting(-1);
        ini_set('display_errors', 1);
        error_reporting(E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT & ~E_USER_NOTICE & ~E_USER_DEPRECATED);

        $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
        $whoops->pushHandler(new \Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());
        $whoops->register();

        throw new Exception("Whoops exception testing");

        break;

    case 'testing':

        break;

    case 'production':

        break;

    default:

        exit(1);
}
```

Whoops handle the error occurred in `index.php` file, but not when error happen in Controller or Model, it seems that CI error handler kinda catch the error first before Whoops does.

Next attempt was to also register Whoops in `MY_Controller.php` construct, it works, but only Exception was handle by Whoops, a simple syntax error like forgetting semicolon still handle by CI error handler. It kinda weird thought to instance Whoops handler in to different places.

Reference:
[Codeigniter + Whoops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45786078/codeigniter-whoops)

Comment: If you get a syntax error or the like - you fix it. It's not an exception. it's a stuff up!

Comment: Yes, syntax error or the like is something that needed to be fixed, but the question is why it's not handled by Whoops? afaik, when using Laravel even syntax error is handled by Whoops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it working nicely by doing the following:

1. Make sure hooks are enabled in `config/config.php`

   ```
   $config['enable_hooks'] = true;
   ```
2. Add a hook in `config/hooks.php`

   ```
   $hook['pre_system'][] = array(
     'class'    => 'WhoopsHook',
     'function' => 'bootWhoops',
     'filename' => 'WhoopsHook.php',
     'filepath' => 'hooks',
     'params'   => array()
   );
   ```
3. Create a new file `hooks/WhoopsHook.php` with the following code:

   ```
   <?php
   class WhoopsHook {
       public function bootWhoops() {
           $whoops = new \Whoops\Run;
           $whoops->pushHandler(new Whoops\Handler\PrettyPageHandler());
           $whoops->register();
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm using xampp as development environment. I have my Codeigniter app in \htdocs\mycitest . TO install woops with composer, in which directory should i go tu run the "composer require filp/whoops" command? Thank you for confirming